# Use GR Arrow Styles in Julia.Plots

Tags: julia, annotate, arrows

I'd like to annotate a point in a plot I draw using julia Plots with the GR backend.
I get the arrows drawn with

```
plot([(pos1), (pos2)], line=:arrow)
```

As expected, this draws a `:simple` arrow.
However, I can not figure out how to get `:filled` or `:closed` arrows. 
I have tried several permutations:

```
plt1 = plot([(pos1), (pos2)], line=:arrow, arrow=arrow(:closed))
plt2 = plot([(pos1), (pos2)], line=:arrow, arrow=:closed)
```

And also directly calling the GR function

```
plt3 = plot([(pos1), (pos2)], line=:arrow, arrow_style=arrow(:closed))
plt4 = plot([(pos1), (pos2)], line=:arrow, arrow=arrow_style(:closed))
```

Is there a way to switch arrow styles on Julia.Plots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to get rid of the `line = :arrow` keyword argument. `line` in Plots is a [magic argument](http://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/attributes/#magic-arguments-1) and `line = :arrow` will be converted to `arrow = :arrow` internally during the preprocessing pipeline, overwriting the provided arrow attribute.

```
plot(rand(2), rand(2), arrow = :closed, lims = (0, 1))
```

gives

[image]